# Isometric 3d collision detection

Tags: javascript, collision, detection, isometric

I'm making an isometric map for a game, I can draw it, but I don't know how to implement a sort of 3d collision detection without Threejs or other 3d library.

It is possible? Maybe make the block an Object can help? I have searched, but I found only libraries.

This is my JavaScript code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
 width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
 height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
 stop = false;

var tw, th;
var player;

setup();
draw();

function setup(){
 ctx.translate(width/2,50);

 tw = 60; //tile width
 th = 30; // tile height
  player = new Player(2,3,3);

};

function draw(){

 ctx.clearRect(-width/2,-50,width*1.5,height+50);

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        drawBlock(i,j,1,tw,th);
      }
    }

    if(!stop){
     requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
}

function drawBlock(x,y,z,w,h){

 var top = "#eeeeee",
     right = '#cccccc',
     left = '#999999';

 ctx.save();
 ctx.translate((x-y)*w/2,(x+y)*h/2);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(w/2,h/2-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(-w/2,h/2-z*h);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = top;
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(-w/2,h/2-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h);
 ctx.lineTo(-w/2,h/2);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = left;
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(w/2,h/2-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h);
 ctx.lineTo(w/2,h/2);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = right;
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.restore();

}

function drawTile(x,y,stroke,col){

 ctx.save();
 ctx.translate((x-y)*tw/2,(x+y)*th/2);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.lineTo(tw/2,th/2);
 ctx.lineTo(0,th);
 ctx.lineTo(-tw/2,th/2);
 ctx.closePath();
 if(stroke){
  ctx.stroke();
 }else{
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fill();
 }

 ctx.restore();

}

function Player(x,y,z){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
  this.w = 10; //width
  this.h = 10; //height
}
```

```css
canvas{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Do all of your objects use 90° angles exclusively?

Comment: @destoryer yes they do

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is cube collision. The first result I get for googling that is an article on MDN named [3D collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection#AABB_vs._AABB):

> Mathematically this would look like so:
>
> ```
> f(A,B) = (AminX <= BmaxX ∧ AmaxX >= BminX) ∧ (AminY <= BmaxY ∧ AmaxY >= BminY) ∧ (AminZ <= BmaxZ ∧ AmaxZ >= BminZ)
> ```
>
> And in JavaScript, we'd use this:
>
> ```
> function intersect(a, b) {
>   return (a.minX <= b.maxX && a.maxX >= b.minX) &&
>          (a.minY <= b.maxY && a.maxY >= b.minY) &&
>          (a.minZ <= b.maxZ && a.maxZ >= b.minZ);
> }
> ```